# Funcionalidad drag & drop

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy iniciando en la funcionalidad drag & drog. Tengo tres div usando bootstrap uno al lado de otro. En el primero (izquierdo) los muestro las tareas con prioridad alta. El del medio las tareas con prioridad media y el de la derecha las tareas de prioridad baja:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los div inicialmente están vacíos y dependiendo de una consulta relleno esos div con la información de cada tarea. Por cada tarea se agrega un div. les muestro el código html:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasRight" aria-labelledby="offcanvasRightLabel" style="width: 45%;"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #FF5555; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
                <div style="background: #FF5555; height: 100%; width: 30%; text-align: left; color: white; padding-left: 12px">Alto</div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Tarea y presione Enter" id="addTareaAltoText" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="Agregar nueva tarea" type="button" id="addTareaAltoButton"><span class="icon-plus1"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div id="inputs-high" class="draggable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #03C04A; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
                <div style="background: #03C04A; height: 100%; width: 30%; text-align: left; color: white; padding-left: 12px">Medio</div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Tarea y presione Enter" id="addTareaMedioText" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="Agregar nueva tarea" type="button" id="addTareaMedioButton"><span class="icon-plus1"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div id="inputs-medium" class="draggable"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div style="border-bottom: 2px solid #54A7F5; height: 30px; text-align: left;">
                <div style="background: #54A7F5; height: 100%; width: 30%; text-align: left; color: white; padding-left: 12px">Bajo</div>
            </div><br>
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Añadir Tarea y presione Enter" id="addTareaBajoText" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary hint--top hint--rounded" aria-label="Agregar nueva tarea" type="button" id="addTareaBajoButton"><span class="icon-plus1"></span></button>
            </div>
            <div id="inputs-low" class="draggable"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Código jquery y ajax donde lleno los datos de las tareas:

```
function buscarTareas(opcion, fInicio, fFin){//Función para buscar los  
    var dataString = 'opcion='+opcion+'&grupo='+grupo+'&tipoUser='+tipoUser+'&canal='+canal+'&userid='+userid+'&fInicio='+fInicio+'&fFin='+fFin+'&user_final='+user_final;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'cliente_tareas_buscar.php',
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data){
            $("#inputs-high").html('');
            $("#inputs-medium").html('');
            $("#inputs-low").html('');
            if($("#inputs-high").children().length != 0) {
                            
            } else {    
                $("#inputs-high").html(data.contenidoHigh);
            }
            if($("#inputs-medium").children().length != 0) {
                            
            } else {    
                $("#inputs-medium").html(data.contenidoMedium);
            }
            if($("#inputs-low").children().length != 0) {
                            
            } else {    
                $("#inputs-low").html(data.contenidoLow);
            }
                        
        },
        error: function (jqXHR1,textStatus1,errorThrown1) {
            Swal.fire({icon: 'error',title: $('#titulo_aviso').val(),html: 'Se produjo el error: '+jqXHR1.status+'-'+textStatus1+' al eliminar el evento',showConfirmButton: false,timer: 2000});
        }
    });
}
```

Configuración del drag & drop:

```
// Configuración del arrastre para las tareas
$(".draggable").draggable({
    revert: "invalid", // Hace que el elemento vuelva a su posición original si no se suelta en un área válida
    helper: "clone" // Clona el elemento durante el arrastre
});

// Configuración de las áreas donde se pueden soltar las tareas
$(".inputs-high, .inputs-medium, .inputs-low").droppable({
    accept: ".draggable", // Define qué elementos pueden ser soltados en estas áreas
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    // Lógica a ejecutar cuando un elemento es soltado en esta área
    var draggedElement = ui.helper.clone();
    $(this).append(draggedElement);

    // Aquí debes agregar la lógica para actualizar la tarea en la base de datos con la nueva prioridad
    // Puedes obtener información sobre la tarea desde el elemento clonado o mediante algún otro método
    // Luego, realiza la actualización en la base de datos a través de una llamada AJAX u otro medio.
                }
});
```

Averiguando encontré que en JQUERY está la herramienta jQuery UI, lo que necesito es que cuando seleccione una tarea alta por ejemplo me permita arrastrarlo y si por ejemplo lo suelto en el div donde están las tareas de prioridad media, se actualice el campo de la prioridad en media, en cualquier lado donde suelte debe actualizar la prioridad, veo que se arrastra pero al soltarlo me devuelve a la posición inicial. Según lo que averigue es que por que tengo la opción revert: "invalid" configurada así. Pero en el div está inicialmente vacío y después dependiendo de la búsqueda se llena. Si alguien sabe como puedo hacer para resolverlo. Este es el código PHP de como lleno la información, coloco sólo un fragmento porque las demás se llenan igual, disculpen si es muy largo la pregunta y la situación expuesta:

```
$data['contenidoHigh'].='<div class="inputs-high draggable">';
     $data['contenidoHigh'].='<div class="left"></div>';
          $data['contenidoHigh'].='<div class="center">';
               $data['contenidoHigh'].='<p>';
                    $data['contenidoHigh'].='<a href="#" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasRight" aria-controls="offcanvasRight" class="number_tarea link-secondary link-offset-2 link-underline-opacity-25 link-underline-opacity-100-hover hint--left-middle hint--rounded" aria-label="Detallar Tarea '.$asunto.'">';
                         $data['contenidoHigh'].='<label for="">'.$asunto.'</label>';
                    $data['contenidoHigh'].='</a>';
               $data['contenidoHigh'].='</p>';
               $data['contenidoHigh'].='<label for=""><span class="icon-calendar1"></span> '.$fecha.'</label>';
        $data['contenidoHigh'].='</div>';
        $data['contenidoHigh'].='<div class="right">';          
             $data['contenidoHigh'].='<label for="">'.$nombreEstado.'</label><br>';
             $data['contenidoHigh'].='<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic mixed styles example">';
                  $data['contenidoHigh'].='<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="font-size: 10px;" value="'.$id.'"><span class="icon-edit"></span></button>';
                  $data['contenidoHigh'].='<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" style="font-size: 10px;" value="'.$id.'"><span class="icon-trash"></span></button>';
                        $data['contenidoHigh'].='</div>';               
             $data['contenidoHigh'].='</div>';                  
        $data['contenidoHigh'].='</div>';
```